# Как реализовать фильтрацию элементов по категориям?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Подскажите как можно реализовать фильтрацию элементов по категориям.

Например, есть секция в которой располагается список категорий и ниже картинки, нужно, чтобы при клике по категории оставались только соответствующие ей картинки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый просто способ - выборка по определенному атрибуту, например, `data-filter`:

```js
$('.filters a').on('click', function() {
  $('.filters li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent('li').addClass('active'); // выделяем выбранную категорию

  var cat = $(this).attr('data-filter'); // определяем категорию

  if (cat == 'all') { // если all
    $('.products li').show(); // отображаем все позиции
  } else { // если не all
    $('.products li').hide(); // скрываем все позиции
    $('.products li[data-filter="' + cat + '"]').show(); // и отображаем позиции из соответствующей категории
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

li {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.filters li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.filters li.active a {
  color: #f00;
}

.products:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.products li {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="filters">
  <li class="active"><a data-filter="all">all</a></li>
  <li><a data-filter="cat1">cat1</a></li>
  <li><a data-filter="cat2">cat2</a></li>
  <li><a data-filter="cat3">cat3</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="products">
  <li data-filter="cat1">cat1</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat1">cat1</li>
  <li data-filter="cat3">cat3</li>
  <li data-filter="cat1">cat1</li>
  <li data-filter="cat1">cat1</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat3">cat3</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat1">cat1</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat3">cat3</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat1">cat1</li>
  <li data-filter="cat1">cat1</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat2">cat2</li>
  <li data-filter="cat3">cat3</li>
</ul>
```